# spark dataframe save as partitioned table very slowly

Tags: apache-spark

```
df.write.partitionBy("par").format("orc").saveAsTable("mytable")
```

hello everybody , when i save a spark dataframe as a partitioned hive table, the process is very very slow, does anybody know why? Are there any parameters which should be tuned?

Comment: try `df.repartition("par").write.partitionBy("par").format("orc").saveAsTable("mytable")`

Comment: are you sure the actual process of writing the table is slow? Because when you write your table, all previous transformations are applied first (as they are lazy) . So what you see may be the time of your entire pipline instead of just the writing action.

Comment: Ok, i will have a try, but firstly , why would df.repartition("par") operation work? Can you explain it ?

Comment: How many partitions shall be created if you are partioning by "Par". Is it enormous ?

Comment: You method perfectly resolve my problem. Thank you very much . About 1 500 partitions will be created.  I always think the parameter of reparttiion should be integer . in this case , what is the function of repartition .

Comment: @shengshanzhang I added my comment as an answer which you could now accept

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that the dataframe-partitions are not "aligned" with the hive partitions. This will create many small files per hive partition. This is because each partition of data dataframe contains some data for the hive partition.

Try to repartition the dataframe first on the same column:

```
df.repartition("par").write.partitionBy("par").format("orc")‌​.saveAsTable("mytabl‌​e")
```

Comment: b.rdd.getNumPartitions()=1 b.repartition("par").rdd.getNumPartitions() =200 i found without repartition , the partitions number is 1 , while with repartion operation , the number is 200 . May the number of  partitions be the reason？